# Symfony2 splitting translation files

Tags: symfony

I create a multilanguage App in Symfony. At this point i have two languages, german and english. I create in my bundle two files.

App\UserBundle\Resources\translations\messages.de.xlf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>msg.email</source>
                <target>E-Mail</target>
            </trans-unit>
         </body>
      </file>
 </xliff>
```

App\UserBundle\Resources\translations\messages.en.xlf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="1">
                <source>msg.email</source>
                <target>Email</target>
            </trans-unit>
         </body>
      </file>
 </xliff>
```

Now i have about 200 translation strings. Can i split a translation file into many files? As example  "messages.en-1.xlf, messages.de-1.xlf, messages.en-2.xlf, messages.de-2.xlf" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use domains. All your files will be named as `domain1.en.xlf`, `domain1.de.xlf`, `domain2.en.xlf`, `domain2.de.xlf` and so on.

More documentation you can find here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/introduction.html#using-message-domains.
And here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translations-in-templates

Also you will need to change your template with something like this:

```
{{ message|trans({here_you_can_put_your_parameters_or_use_empty_array}, 'domain1') }}
```